# Query within EXISTS doesn't work but with Exists it works

Tags: sql-server

I have a doubt about below query. I am able to run below query as it is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DRS_MessageActivity HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(ISNULL(DataMessageHeartbeatTime, 0)), GETUTCDATE()) >= 5) 
BEGIN 
    print 'worked';
END
```

... and it prints "**Worked**" but when I check the internal query,

```
SELECT * FROM DRS_MessageActivity HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(ISNULL(DataMessageHeartbeatTime, 0)), GETUTCDATE()) >= 5
```

... it fails with error "Column 'DRS_MessageActivity.ReplicationID' **is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause**."

interestingly, it doesn't give my any syntactical errors but it fails

My research: Below all works

-- Just MAX

```
select MAX(DataMessageHeartbeatTime) FROM DRS_MessageActivity
```

-- Just ISNULL

```
SELECT ISNULL(DataMessageHeartbeatTime, 0) FROM DRS_MessageActivity
```

-- just Max + ISNULL

```
select MAX(ISNULL(DataMessageHeartbeatTime, 0)) FROM DRS_MessageActivity
```

-- Just DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(ISNULL(DataMessageHeartbeatTime, 0)), GETUTCDATE())  FROM DRS_MessageActivity
```

I have ReplicationID as one of the columns but not sure why it is failing.. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT *` in `EXISTS()` subqueries doesn't actually represent all of the columns.  You are simply looking for the existence of rows.

Similarly, you can use `SELECT 1` or `SELECT 12848123` and it will work the same way.

SQL Server is smart enough to infer how to `GROUP` rows to adhere to your `HAVING` clause inside the `EXISTS()` without explicitly being told, because you're not actually returning a result set.

However, if you attempt to run the same query outside of `EXISTS()`, the `SELECT *` now means `SELECT all columns`, and you will need to explicitly `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the columns per usual.

Comment: Awesome.. that's the explanation that makes sense to me. .. Thanks @Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` only checks that a dataset would be returned, so that fact you have used a `SELECT *` and no `GROUP BY` doesn't actually matter (as the `SELECT` isn't evaluatd). The syntax of the query outside of the `EXISTS` is invalid, due to the lack of a `GROUP BY` and that you are attempting to use `SELECT *`.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by that a dataset would be returned

Comment: Not sure how else I can elaborate on that, it was quite concise. If a dataset would be returned from the query inside the `EXISTS`...